# A class which does not need an instance

Tags: c++, class, instance

Is it possible to make a class which does not need to be instantiated? In other words, is it possible to use functions of that class without having an instance of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make all member functions and variables static, but then one starts to wonder why it should be a class, and not a namespace.

There is a good reason, though: you may want to use a class template like this.  C++14 will add variable templates, which make the same possible without a class.  A class also allows access control; you can fake this for the non-template case with anonymous namespaces, but a class may be more natural.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **static functions**, those are bound to the Class, not an instance.

```
class Test{
    static void 
    doSomething()
    {
        std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Test::doSomething(); //prints "something" without instance of Test
}
```

Otherwise you could build a Singleton, in which case the class itself would hold the instance, but I am not sure if this is what you wanted to know...

Comment: Using static functions is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Although bear in mind that this is rarely useful, since you could just as well define a function called `doSomething` outside any class. You can even put it in a namespace called `Test`. It's often useful with templates, though, since a class can be a template parameter but a namespace can't. So you can group together functions into classes and then tell a template to use that class.

Comment: @Steve-Jessop to be honest, I never use static functions beside the singleton pattern, to get an instance. In object oriented programming this is not the best practice I think, but he asked for it, so I answer ;)

Comment: @Theolodis: oh yes, my caution doesn't mean the answer is in any way wrong :-)

Answer (score 2):

A static method can be called without creating an instance of the class.

```
class CMyClass
{
    public:
    static void Method1()
    {
        printf("Method1\n");
    }
};

CMyClass::Method1();    // Prints "Method1".
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. If you want to use of class without having instance of it, you must use **static** functions.

Answer (score 0):

For that you should use the `static` modifier. See documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx

Comment: I saw that later, I just changed the link. :)

Comment: Exactly, I was talking about the `static` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create private constructor of such class with static methods to prevent from creating any instances